# How can we appreciate stored-program concept?

Tags: concept

To appreciate something, you need contrast with something else. How can our generation appreciate the concept of stored-program when we haven't seen any other way of computing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way out seems to me is that know how the earlier computers used to work and then compare them side by side with stored-program computers.

Answer (score 0):

Need more data to build any kind of concept. Compare in one thing, but another is the description of the concept.